# How do i unzip this file when this shows up

Tags: 12.04

```
(precise)thecreeperdestryer@localhost:~$ unzip VoidLauncher Linux.zip
unzip:  cannot find or open VoidLauncher, VoidLauncher.zip or VoidLauncher.ZIP.
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
  unzip VoidLauncher\ Linux.zip
```

\ is for escape sequence for space in file name.

Answer (score 1):

This is a typical problem with spaces/special character. In bash if you press tab to auto complete the file name, it will expand the file name as in above answer by cham3333.

In case when copying and pasting the file name,  I find it convinient to use double quotes.
So following will do the trick

```
unzip "VoidLauncher Linux.zip"
```